# screenName confusion in Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have learnt integrating Google Analytics in my Android app from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). But, I am unable to understand the priorities of the screen name mentioned in xml and mentioned programatically via setScreenName. If both are mentioned which one will I see in the reports? Should I use any one approach instead of both? I am not providing code because it's available in the above-mentioned page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer for yourself by logging the screen name to the console after you set it:

```
// log which screen name Google Analytics is associated with right now
String screenName = tracker.get("&cd");
Log.d("GA Screen Name", screenName == null ? "(not set)" : screenName);
```